# What are the specific benefits of angular.js vs. ember.js

Tags: ember.js, angularjs, angular-ui

I have been researching between these two guys this week to work in a project next year. What I have found so far is that angular is better for small/medium scale projects and ember would be good for high scale projects.

I have been playing with angular and it looks great. It has couple rules, which keeps the developers on the same page.

Well, let me know your thoughts. Thanks community!

Comment: So what's the question?  Vote to close.

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/, and rephrase it to something like "What are the specific benefits of angluar.js vs. ember.js"

Comment: This Quora thread may be of interest: http://www.quora.com/Ember-js/Which-one-of-angular-js-and-ember-js-is-the-better-choice

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/